# JavaScript not working in Rails -- Causing delete path not to work, and some gems

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-wysiwyg

So what's happening right now is that I'm trying to delete a particular resource -- a `post`. When I click the delete button, it just leads me to the show view of the post.

I also have a WYSIWYG gem that works off of JavaScript that is no longer performing. I've included the JS tag in my application file like so:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

In my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5/b3
//= require_tree .
```

`jquery-rails` is also in my Gemfile.

Any ideas?

JS Console:

[image]

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery_ujs.js:398
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined affix.js:138
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined alert.js:89
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined button.js:108
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined carousel.js:206
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined collapse.js:171
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined dropdown.js:148
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined tab.js:126
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined transition.js:49
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined scrollspy.js:154
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined modal.js:244
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined tooltip.js:400
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined popover.js:111
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined core-b3.js:383
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helper' of undefined blueimp-gallery-fullscreen.js:26
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helper' of undefined blueimp-gallery-indicator.js:26
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helper' of undefined blueimp-gallery-video.js:26
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helper' of undefined blueimp-gallery-vimeo.js:26
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helper' of undefined blueimp-gallery-youtube.js:26
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined blueimp-gallery.js:56
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined demo.js:15
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined galleria-1.3.5.js:6863
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined galleria.flickr.js:384
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.blueimp-gallery.js:33
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js?body=1:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined application.js:20
```

**What I've tried**

I changed the `link_to` to `button_to` to see what would happen. It allows for the deletion of the post -- without confirmation, though. It doesn't really fix the JavaScript issue.

Comment: There are no "errors". What's happening is that "When I click the delete button, it just leads me to the show view of the post" instead of deleting it." If we can solve this problem, I'm sure the WYSIWYG gem will fix itself. @apneadiving

Comment: check your js console

Comment: Where is the js console located @apneadiving

Comment: In Chrome, press CMD-ALT-i (Mac) / CTRL-ALT-i (Win) to open the developer tools. Please switch to the Console tab and tell us which errors are reported there.

Comment: Updated the original post @janfoeh

Comment: That's actually a terrible photo. Let me try to make it more readable.

Comment: jQuery is missing. Does your gemfile include `gem 'jquery-rails'`?

Comment: Yeah -- I've got that in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to the top of the head of my application file.